# MacBook M1 How to bypass USB devices to docker container?

Tags: macos, usb, apple-silicon, docker

I've faced with the issue that I cannot forward USB device from MacOS to docker container based on Ubuntu.

I run docker image in the following way:

`docker run --rm -v /dev:/dev -p 8080:8080 -p 8081:8081 custom_image_based_on_ubuntu`

Looks like MacOS does not mount newly found USB devices to /dev folder like it is done in Linux systems.

Do somebody know how to do it ?